# If statement not running properly

Tags: php

This is my PHP code, essentially I check the user's country, and if it matches the allowed countries, I let the affiliate code to run. Well for some reason it's not running

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('geoip-lookup '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
if($_SESSION['check']!= 1 && ($output == 'US' || $output== 'AU' || $output== 'GB' || $output== 'CA'))
{
$submission = $_POST['submission_id'];
$_SESSION['check']=1;
echo '<div class="shareasale"><img src="https://shareasale.com/sale.cfm?amount=0.00&tracking=';
echo $submission;
echo '&transtype=lead&perlead=25.00&merchantID=###" width="1" height="1"></div>';
}
?>
```

I think there is a problem with the OR bit, because when I added an else if to check variables, I got $output as US and $_SESSION['check'] as blank. Which means the if statement should have run properly.

Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Did you try debugging it by printing statements and states at various locations within the code?

Comment: When it's "not running", what are the `var_dump`s of `$_SESSION['check']` and `$output`? Right before the `if` statement, have a line of code that does `var_dump($_SESSION['check'], $output);`

Comment: did you try using trim on $output? maybe you have a new line or a space before or after what you see in your browser..

Comment: I put the code before and $_SESSION['check'] is blank and $output is US and for after the else if shows up the same things. It just doesn't seem like the if statement is getting triggered, so the problem is most likely in that first if line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have a `session_start()` call, so your $_SESSION array won't be populated, so there's no `check` value in there to compare against.

As well, are you sure that your shell_exec() call is actually working? It's possible that geoip-lookup is not in the path of whatever shell PHP is executing to run that program. The output may also contain line breaks, carriage returns, etc..., which your exact string matche requirements in the if() call is not taking into account. `$output` may actually be "US\n" and not just "US".

Comment: oh yeah, that I have at the top of the file, so I forgot to copy it...it's there

Comment: i ran it as an else if to check the variables, and it came out as US, so that should be fine as well

Comment: @Andrew, what did you do to verify there is no  `"\n"`?

Comment: var_dump($output) should report "string(2)" if there is no \n or other hidden characters.

Comment: for vardump I got NULL string(3) "US "

Comment: So.. yeah. it's a 3 character string, indicating there IS one hidden character. Try doing `$output = trim($output)` to eliminate any whitespace/hidden chars around the string.